# ZendX_JQuery elements in Zend_Form

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I have a form that extends Twitter_Form (A Twitter bootstrap css form) which in turn extends Zend_Form. I want to add ZendX_JQuery elements in Zend_Form, but i get errors because of decorators

The error is

```
Cannot render jQuery form element without at least one decorator implementing the 'ZendX_JQuery_Form_Decorator_UiWidgetElementMarker'
 Default decorator for this marker interface is the 'ZendX_JQuery_Form_Decorator_UiWidgetElement'. Hint: The ViewHelper decorator does not render jQuery elements
```

The form class is:

```
class Application_Form_Classes extends Twitter_Form {

   $autocomplete = new ZendX_JQuery_Form_Element_Autocomplete('demo-input-local');
   $autocomplete->setJQueryParam('url','http://.../something.php');

   $this->addElement($autocomplete);


   $this->addElement("submit", "register", array("label" => "Register"));}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the custom multipleautocomplete viewhelper to my `Twitter_Form` as a subform. If there is any alternate way to do, please post an answer.

```
class Application_Form_Classes extends Twitter_Form{

   public function init(){

       $jqueryform = new ZendX_JQuery_Form();

       $multiautocomplete = new ZendX_JQuery_Form_Element_Multiautocomplete('demoinputlocal');
       $multiautocomplete->setJQueryParam('url','http://..../something.php');

        $jqueryform->addElement($multiautocomplete);

        $this->addSubForm($jqueryform, "jqueryform");

       $this->addElement("submit", "register", array("label" => "Register"));
       $this->addElement("reset", "reset", array("label" => "Reset"));

    }
}
```